# Conditioning disable dropdown based on input text value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making an autocomplete feature. I want to create a condition, if `company-name` has a value, the dropdown will have the disable attribute and the arrow box background will be gray. I've made the code as below, but it's still not working properly. Is there something wrong with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $('.company-name').on('keyup',function(){
  const companyValue = $('.company-name').val();
  //console.log(companyValue)
  if(companyValue !== ''){
    console.log('okay');
    
    $("select[name='account-industrySize-id']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("select[name='account-industrySize-id']").parent().addClass('disable');
    $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").parent().addClass('disable');
    $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
    $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").parent().addClass('disable');
  }
  })
  
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 28px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px lightgrey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px lightgrey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info-row{
  margin-bottom:30px;
}

.select-wrapper.disable:before{
  background-color:grey;
}

.select-wrapper:before {
    content: 'V';
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 9px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #cb4645;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-row">
   <div class="value">
       <input type="text" class="company-name">
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="info-row">
   <div class="value">
       <div class="select-wrapper">
           <select name="account-legalEntityType-id" id="legal-entity-type" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
              <option value="" style="display:none">PT</option>
              <option value="11" style="color: black;">Lainnya</option>
              <option value="1" style="color: black;">PT</option>
              <option value="2" style="color: black;">CV</option>
            </select>    
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="info-row">
   <div class="value">
       <div class="select-wrapper">
           <select name="account-industryType-id" id="industry-type" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
              <option value="" style="display:none">Medical</option>
              <option value="11" style="color: black;">Others</option>
              <option value="1" style="color: black;">Financial</option>
              <option value="2" style="color: black;">Technology</option>
            </select>    
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="info-row">
   <div class="value">
       <div class="select-wrapper">
           <select name="account-indsutrySize-id" id="industry-size" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
              <option value="" style="display:none">0</option>
              <option value="10" style="color: black;">10</option>
              <option value="20" style="color: black;">20</option>
              <option value="30" style="color: black;">30</option>
            </select>    
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are looking for a select like this `select[name='account-industrySize']` but the name of the select is `account-indsutrySize-id` not `account-indsutrySize`. So either use `select[name='account-industrySize-id']` or `select[name^='account-industrySize']`

Comment: Also note you have a type error in `account-indsutrySize-id`

Comment: my bad, thank you for correction @CarstenLøvboAndersen